# Email for newsletters changed without any notification

Tags: discussion

I just found out that the email from which Stack Exchange newsletters are sent were changed without any notice. This is a nuisance for those of us who have email filter setup by the sender. I am getting a ton of newsletters in right in my inbox. It would be nice if you revert the change, or at least send an email letting users know.

Answer (score 13):

Apologies for the lack of communication around this change. It was intended to be transparent, but we didn’t consider the sender address when making the change. In addition we didn’t expect our users to be very appreciative of an unsolicited email (we have upwards of 300k users subscribed to a newsletter). In retrospect maybe a post on meta.SE would have been appropriate here.

I’m afraid it’s not going to be reverted though, we can’t send from the stackoverflow.com / stackexchange.com domains for a variety of reasons. If it’s a big problem to update your filters you can unsubscribe from all or manage the newsletters you’re subscribed to in the [newsletter management](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/newsletters/current) screen.

Comment: I am not sure why this is downvoted. One of the newsletters ended up in my spam bin by accident. Does this not belong here? I was directed here from the "feedback" link from the newsletter. Who's going to send feedback if you are going to downvoted like this? Any comments?

Comment: @wbkang And why are you asking Dean if he knows about the downvotes? Only the downvoters know why they downvoted you. And whinning about downvotes: not cool.

Comment: @yivi How did I "whine?" Did you read what I said at all? I posted here because the "feedback" link on the newsletter directed me here to post a question instead. I think there is a problem when the only method of "feedback" submission gets you random downvotes.